Why do direct conversion receivers amplify only after mixing?
The vast majority of the simple direct conversion receivers I've seen amplify only after mixing.  The RF is filtered before mixing, but not amplified at all.  For example (from Solid State Design for the Radio Amateur):

Many superhets do the same, only amplifying the audio frequency after all mixing is done (for example, the NorCal 40.
Why? Since the RF signal may be only 1uV, and the LO is perhaps 10^6 times greater, it would seem to me that we'd expect better results doing some of the amplification beforehand, so that the mixer can mix two inputs of similar strength.
I understand that we want to defer some of the amplification until after the final filtering, so that we amplify only the signal, and do not have nonlinearities and intermodulation to deal with, and this by definition requires us to first mix and filter.  But why don't we need to do at least some amplification before mixing?
Is there any way to characterize the minimal signal strength a mixer requires? Or to quantify how mixing is impacted when the two signals are of hugely different strengths?

One of the terms you're looking for is noise figure. Note that your reference need not be exhaustive; lack of example is not proof of nonexistence.

You could use an RF BP amplifier before the mixer ... Noise should be higher but sensitivity should be "greater" ... Note that using an amplifier should risk also cross-modulation (because of non-linearity). Non-amplifying is used in spectrum analyzers because of non-linearities.


I understand that we want to defer some of the amplification until
after the final filtering, so that we amplify only the signal, and do
not have nonlinearities and intermodulation to deal with, and this by
definition requires us to first mix and filter.

Yes, this is of paramount importance in a receiver with wide dynamic range. It is difficult to make a mixer that has low intermodulation...especially 3rd order intermodulation products. A few of these fall back into the low-pass filter's passband and cannot easily be filtered out by the low-pass filter. If an amplifier precedes the mixer, its gain makes intermodulation at the mixer worse. We'd like to keep signal levels down as low as possible going into the mixer, yielding high dynamic range.
At the other extreme (for weak signals), signals might benefit from a preamp between antenna and mixer, so that noise introduced by the mixer doesn't mask them. It is a general "rule-of-thumb" that amplifier noise figure is superior to mixer noise figures.
For amateur radio high-frequency bands, noise coming in along with signals is so high that preamps are not needed...even weak signals are not masked by a decent mixer's noise. This is not so at higher frequencies where noise levels are lower and a low-noise preamp helps overcome noise introduced by a mixer.

Since the RF signal may be only 1uV, and the LO is perhaps 10^6
times greater, it would seem to me that we'd expect better results
doing some of the amplification beforehand, so that the mixer can mix
two inputs of similar strength.

There's a common misunderstanding here.
This might be valid for a multiplier circuit, but most every mixer acts by switching. This is so for NORCAL 40A mixer - a Gilbert cell type. The SA602 oscillator input on pins 6,7 is run at high amplitude, so that its four bridge mixing transistors are driven hard enough to act as switches. Two are ON while the other two are OFF. So the small-amplitude signal is multiplied by +1, or alternately by -1.
While it is possible to reduce local oscillator signal amplitude, why would you want to multiply by say, +0.5 and alternately by -0.5? The desired mixer output would be reduced by half.
A diode-ring mixer is also a switching-type mixer where the local oscillator delivers power to the switching diodes significantly higher than the largest expected signal at the input port. Driving the local oscillator port hard tends to reduce distortion products.

Is there any way to characterize the minimal signal strength a mixer
requires? Or to quantify how mixing is impacted when the two signals
are of hugely different strengths?

IP3 spec (third-order intercept point) of a mixer is often used as a figure-of-merit to characterize strong-signal performance for both receivers and mixers. Noise floor sets the weak-signal limit.

The fundamental property of a four-quadrant multiplier applies to mixers. A multiplier has two input waveforms: one of which is signal, while the other is local oscillator.

If local oscillator swings +ve, signal is passed from input to output
When local oscillator swings -ve, signal is passed inverted to output.

The SA602 in NORCAL receivers do something similar, except that input signals between pins 1,2 are first amplified, then these inverted and non-inverted amplified currents are switched between outputs on pins 4,5.
Mixer gain does depend on local oscillator voltage drive on pin 6, but any more than about 300mV p-p doesn't gain you any more, and negatively impacts distortion.

In logic, the XOR function operates like a mixer. It follows the rules of multiplication:

a positive multiplied by a positive gives a positive result
a positive multiplied by a negative gives a negative result
a negative multiplied by a negative gives a positive result

Some phase-locked-loops use XOR similarly to generate difference between VCO and reference oscillator frequencies. This is also a phase detector...or mixer - call it what you like.

Aha! Practical mixers work by switching, and so don't need equality of voltages between LO and RF.  To the contrary, having a weaker RF input lowers mixer intermodulation, improving results, provided the NF of the mixer doesn't swamp out the unamplified signal - which is not usually the case for HF.  Have I understood correctly?

"This might be valid for a multiplier circuit, but most every mixer acts by switching."  Is this true even for a simple single BJT mixer with the LO at the base and the biased RF at the collector (or vice versa)? We should drive the LO as hard as possible, and then we get a switching mixer (not multiplying mixer), and can handle well weak RF?

stuff added to this answer. You can decrease L.O. drive to SA602 pin 6 to make it more like a "linear" multiplier, but you'll have less output. Few do this. Data sheet recommends L.O. of 200mV to 300mV p-p if I recall. Below this, switching becomes weaker, decreasing mixer gain, but also decreasing many distortion products.

I'd recommend always using balanced mixers rather than the single-device that you describe, so that either inverted or non-inverted signal appears at mixer output. You can do this with a SPDT switch and 1:1:1 RF transformer. That's a pretty simple mixer that has excellent performance. https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/146369/Mixer_Musings.pdf
